# UIRefreshControl and UITableView's backgroundVIew

Tags: ios, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableViewController on which I set a backgroundView. This controller has a UIRefreshControl installed. The problem is that when I set a background view, the refresh control is invisible. If I remove the background view, I can see the refresh control.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you appreciate any of the answers below, please mark one of them as the right answer. This will increase your reputation, and the answer composer's.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that in iOS 7, the `UITableView`'s `backgroundView` is drawn above the `UIRefreshControl`. Not sure if this is by design or an issue, but here is a workaround that fixed it for me :

```
   self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition -= 1;
```

This code goes where you set up your `UITableViewController refreshControl` property.

Comment: This works. Here's another perhaps more semantically clear way: `self.refreshControl.layer.zPosition = self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition + 1;`

Comment: This is so ugly but it saved me from my misery. Thanks Champoul!

Comment: This is not a good solution if you have a search bar because it causes the refresh control to appear overtop the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending the background to the back or the refresh control to the front. The refresh control is more than likely just sitting at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that UITableViewController pushes its UIRefreshControl to back to the 0 index during reload (behind its "backgroundView"), regardless at what index you put it in the first place. This is what worked for me (iOS 9): Disable refreshing in IB. Create UIRefreshControl in code and add it to tableView after setting up backgroundView:

```
    let someView = UIView()

    self.tableView.backgroundView = someView

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyTableViewController.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, atIndex: 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

This issue is easily fixed by not using the `self.refreshControl` property on the UITableViewController, instead create you own property for it and it will work just fine.