# UIRefreshControl not showing indicator or title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, pull-to-refresh

I want to implement **Pull To Refresh** to my `UITableViewController` by using `UIRefreshControl`. Here what i tried so far.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     .....
     ////********* Pull to refresh ************/
        UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
        refresh.tintColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
     //   [self.tableView addSubview:refresh];
// [self.refreshControl setEnabled:YES];
        [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(pullToRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.refreshControl = refresh;

    }
    -(void)pullToRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
         [refresh beginRefreshing];
        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing.."];
        [self loadRecentActivities];
    }
```

But when i pull the tableview neither activity indicator nor title is visible, however `pullToRefresh` is called and table refreshed.My app supports **iOS7.0+**.
What i'm missing? Any help would be appreciated?

**Edit:** I'v tried with  `[self.refreshControl setEnabled:YES];` and  `[self.refreshControl setEnabled:YES];` as mentioned in my edited code, but still no luck.
This is how my tableview looks like when i pull it to refresh-[image]

**Final Solution:** For table view background i was using

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Refresh indicator and title was hidden behind the `self.tableView.backgroundView` instead use

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

and it solves my problem. also many thanks to **Balram Tiwari** please see his answer if you still have problem.

Comment: UITableViewController already have a refreshControl, you do not need to add another one.

Comment: That line is commented in my code and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: call [refresh beginRefreshing]. in pullToRefresh thats all. when your task complete [refresh endRefreshing];

Comment: is this made a difference?

Comment: Sorry,same result..no luck

Comment: have you enabled [self.refreshControl setEnabled:YES];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47630/discussion-between-bharat-and-pawan)

Comment: @Bharat : I have replied in your chat As well as here too in my answer.

Comment: Better way to solve this is answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18907625/753603

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you have your refresh controller there in the tableView, but it is behind the navigationBar. (Sounds different, right), Here is the catch,

When you are using code in iOS7, by default the `UIViewController` takes the (`edgesForExtendedLayout`) whole screen. That means your (0,0) will start from the top left corner, underneath the navigationBar.

So your tableView is actually starting from there. So to get rid of it, you just specify the `edgesForExtendedLayout` for your `viewController` in your `viewDidLoad` Method.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

After that it should be visible.

- Before above Fix:

[image: Before Fix]

- After the Fix.

[image: After the Fix]

hope that helps.

Comment: Also just uncomment this line. `[self.tableView addSubview:refresh];`

Comment: Its not working for me..also i think its not due to edgesForExtendedLayout as you can see there is space(marked as red rectangle) when my tableview is being refreshed.

Comment: FYI I'v added a subview on self.navigationController.view ( see-Call/Talk Activity in screenshot) and i tried by removing this, but refresh indicator doesn't appear in either case.

Comment: So what was the issue Bharat ?

Comment: edgesForExtendedLayout and constraints..anyway you helped me a lot thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Just add `self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition -= 1;` under the initialisation code for refreshControl.

Comment: This solution works fine. My background image hid the `UIRefreshControl` in my case...